# Mocking SAP IDoc Server

Tags: java, mocking, jco, idoc

I am using SAP JcoIDocServer.

```
 JCoIDocServer server = JCoIDoc.getServer("SAPSERVER_" + connector.name)
```

I want to know if it possible to mock request for testing to this server. Is there a framework or do I have to build my own?

Comment: Asking for frameworks is off-topic, sorry

Answer (score 1):

If you need to test an iDoc and you don't have an SAP server you can initially use another protocol, for example, SOAP, which will generate answers for you. You can create a custom WSDL starting from the XSD (obviously assuming you have it) and test it using SOAPUI

Answer (score 0):

May be you can create client project and communicate it with your server. Correct option is using SAP NW or SAP PI/XI for real test. If you haven't got any SAP server, you can download SAP NW ABAP trial server.